# Javascript "Class" via Prototypes - Variables Undefined

Tags: javascript, class, undefined

I am working on a countdown timer written in Javascript. Fairly basic really. Just uses `setInterval` for the timing aspect. I wrote it using the prototype method of storing functions and variables so I can create a "class".

I call the code in this fashion.

```
function testTimer() {
    var newTimer = new CDTimer($("#voteTimer"),30,"");
    newTimer.start();
}
```

When the below code runs, `console.log` is printing out `undefined` or `NaN`.

```
function CDTimer (target, duration, callback) {
    this.target = target;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.callback = callback;
}

CDTimer.prototype.start = function() {
    this.start = new Date().getTime();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.update, 1000);
}

CDTimer.prototype.update = function() {
    console.log(this.duration, this.start);
    this.elapsed = this.duration - (new Date().getTime() - this.start) / 1000

    if (this.elapsed < 0) {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.callback();
    }
    else {
        console.log(this.elapsed);
        $(this.target).text(this.elapsed);
    }
}

CDTimer.prototype.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

I must be missing something silly. What is happening to my variables and their values?

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to? You havent created any objects using your constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function called from `setInterval` is provided a `this` which is the window, not the timer.

You may do this :

```
CDTimer.prototype.start = function() {
    this.start = new Date().getTime();
    var _this = this;
    this.interval = setInterval(function(){_this.update()}, 1000);
}
```

Note that the MDN offers [a detailed explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval).

EDIT following comment : if you don't want to create a new variable in the start function, you could do this :

```
CDTimer.prototype.start = function() {
    this.start = new Date().getTime();
    this.interval = setInterval(function(_this){_this.update()}, 1000, this);
}
```

But I'm not sure the readibility is improved by this move of the variable creation and it's not compatible with IE (if you don't patch it, see MDN's solution).

Comment: This was exactly the answer. I see the issue now that you have pointed it out. The `this` was not referring to `CDTimer` since it was in the `function()` scope for `setInterval`. Correct? Also, thanks for linking me to the MDN, I had no idea it existed.

Comment: I wonder, can you skip making a variable by passing a reference to oneself into `function()`. Something like `function(this) { ... }`?

Comment: A solution for new browsers would be to make a [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function. But I don't recommend it and it's not really lighter.

Comment: "The `bind` function is a recent addition to ECMA-262, 5th edition; as such it may not be present in all browsers." That right there is a deal breaker for most. :/

Comment: Thanks for your edit. It offers another good solution but I agree that the first solution seems to be more readable.